# The free semiring on the Boolean monoid

Tags: monoid, semiring, tropical-geometry

Recall the following definitions:

- The **Boolean monoid** is the monoid $\mathbb{B}=(\{0,1\},\max,0)$;
- The **free semiring on a commutative monoid $A$** is the semiring $\mathrm{Free}(A)$ consisting of

  - *The Underlying Commutative Monoid.* The commutative monoid $\mathrm{Free}(A)_+$ defined by
    \begin{align*}
        \mathrm{Free}(A)_+ &\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}n}\\
                           &=\mathbb{N}\oplus A\oplus(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}A)\oplus(A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}A\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}A)\oplus\cdots;
    \end{align*}
  - *The Multiplication.* The map
    $$\mathrm{Free}(A)_+\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{Free}(A)_+\to\mathrm{Free}(A)_+$$
    obtained as follows:

    - First we write
      $$\mathrm{Free}(A)_+\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{Free}(A)_+\cong\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigoplus_{\substack{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\\n+m=k}}A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}k};$$
    - Then we iterate the unit and multiplication morphisms
      \begin{align*}
          \eta_{A} &\colon \mathbb{N}  \to A,\\
          \mu_{A}  &\colon A\oplus A   \to A
      \end{align*}
      of $A$ to obtain morphisms of the form $(A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}k})^{\oplus k+1}\to A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}k}$;
    - Finally we use these morphisms to get our desired multiplication map
      $$\underbrace{\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigoplus_{\substack{n,m\in\mathbb{N}\\n+m=k}}A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}k}}_{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathrm{Free}(A)_+\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{Free}(A)_+}\to\underbrace{\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{N}}A^{\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}k}}_{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathrm{Free}(A)_+}.$$

**Question.** Does the semiring $\mathrm{Free}(\mathbb{B})$ admit a nice, simple description? Since $\mathbb{B}\otimes_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{B}\cong\mathbb{B}$, it follows that the underlying commutative monoid of $\mathrm{Free}(\mathbb{B})$ is simply $\mathbb{N}\oplus\mathbb{B}\oplus\mathbb{B}\oplus\cdots$, and thus the elements of $\mathrm{Free}(\mathbb{B})$ look like strings of the form $(n,[\text{0 or 1}],[\text{0 or 1}],\cdots)$, with one example of addition in $\mathrm{Free}(\mathbb{B})$ being
$$(n,1,0,1,0,0,\cdots)+(m,1,1,0,0,\cdots)=(n+m,1,1,1,0,0,\cdots).$$
Multiplication is slightly more cumbersome to compute, but is also defined in somewhat a simple way.

The reason I'm curious about this is that I was wondering whether we could somehow relate $\mathrm{Free}(\mathbb{B})$ to the tropical semiring $(\mathbb{N}\cup\{-\infty\},\max,-\infty)$, as we can also write $\mathbb{B}$ like $(\{-\infty,1\},\max,-\infty)$, and then "freely generating addition of $1$ with itself" (as we do when moving from $\mathrm{pt}=\{1\}$ to the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ by taking the free commutative monoid on $\mathrm{pt}$) should hopefully recover $\mathbb{N}\cup\{-\infty\}$.

Comment: I don't understand your description of the free semiring on a monoid $A$. Isn't it the set of functions $A→ℕ$ with finite support?

Comment: The set of functions $A\to\mathbb{N}$ with finite support is the monoid semiring $\mathbb{N}[A]$ of $A$, the semiring version of [group rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring). $\mathbb{N}[A]$ and what I call $\mathrm{Free}(A)$ above are not the same thing, although they are both free constructions: $\mathbb{N}[-]$ is the left adjoint to the functor sending a semiring $(R,+,\cdot,0,1)$ to its underlying _multiplicative_ monoid $(R,\cdot,1)$, while $\mathrm{Free}$ is the left adjoint to the functor sending $R$ to its underlying _additive_ monoid $(R,+,0)$.

Comment: Ok thanks, this clarifies things.

Comment: @Dabouliplop It's my pleasure :)